# Docker able to search but not able to pull behind proxy

Tags: docker

I am a newbie to Docker and getting hands on with Docker Toolbox in my PC which is behind a corporate proxy. After some SO answers I was able to solve X509 Unauth cert and Proxy issues. Then I was able to do `docker search elastic` which lists all the images in the dockerhub. But when I tried to pull the official image with `docker pull elastic` it throws below error. Tried a couple of solutions from google to do docker login and checked but nothing is working out so far. Any solution would be much apprecicated.

```
raj@localpc MINGW64 ~/DockerWS/app1
$ docker search elastic
NAME                                  DESCRIPTION
      STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
elasticsearch                         Elasticsearch is a powerful open source se
...   2667                [OK]
kibana                                Kibana gives shape to any kind of data  s.
..   1081                [OK]
itzg/elasticsearch                    Provides an easily configurable Elasticsea
...   63                                      [OK]
nshou/elasticsearch-kibana            Elasticsearch-6.1.2 Kibana-6.1.2
      48                                      [OK]
kubernetes/fluentd-elasticsearch      An image that ingests Docker container log
...   21

raj@localpc MINGW64 ~/DockerWS/app1
$ docker pull elastic
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required
```

Thanks.
Raj

Comment: `docker pull elasticsearch` - you need to use the complete name as shown in these search results - `elastic` is not available as image, that's the reason. Instead of searching in the terminal, you could also search in Docker-Hub, e.g. https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that there is no `elastic` image available with exactly that name. The search results show for instance `elasticsearch` or `nshou/elasticsearch-kibana` which have to be used in the `docker pull` command.

`docker pull elasticsearch` would be the solution to use the official ElasticSearch image.

Instead of searching in the terminal you could also use DockerHub directy and copy&paste the `docker pull` command shown in the right section, e.g. https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Oliver Hader, I tried the same but still same error. `raj@localpc MINGW64 ~/DockerWS/app1
$ docker pull elasticsearch
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required
`

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerhub elastic search image has beed [deprecated](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/). You can try to pull from the [official images](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) using:

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks @yamenk, seems something is proceeding but it didnt succeed.                                        `raj@localpc MINGW64 ~/DockerWS/app1
$ docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.2
6.1.2: Pulling from elasticsearch/elasticsearch
af4b0a2388c6: Downloading
111337966b62: Downloading
fbee5813122a: Downloading
022f61aee72e: Downloading
538f1ab05b96: Downloading
10ba2958c64c: Downloading
received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable
`